# TiKZ drawing output

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, tcolorbox

[image]
Please help us how to draw attached images as with `TiKZ`, `PSTricks` or  `tcolorbox`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's quite easy to get started with just one line of TikZ, something like `\draw (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (4.5,1) -- (5,2) -- (0,2) -- cycle;`. So please add a minimal compilable code example (MWE) of what you've tried.

Comment: The blue title box is easy... the non-convex polygonal white box is not really easy with `tcolorbox`

Comment: Why do you want to reproduce that image? Why not just use the usual titles and chapter headings? I hope you won't be offended, but I don't think the image looks very nice.

Comment: Please give some feedback about the answer below

Comment: Please refer my tikz code below, but we need shape above mentioned output: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=none,shade,
      top color=blue!40,
      bottom color=blue!5,
      rounded corners=6pt,
      blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}
    ] {\sffamily\bfseries\large Sample TeX};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: We got an output but still we have some bugs for required output.

Comment: Thank you very much for timely help, output looks great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

A first preliminary version, by changing the frame and interior code of a `tcolorbox` and setting a title attached to the top left as well with a shadow.

The basic configuration is all in the definition of `strangebox`.

The interior/frame code does not adapt to the potential par shape of the box content, i.e. it is possible that the inward kink will be overprinted by text etc.

Use the second mandatory argument of the `strangebox` order to control the amount of bending inside, i.e. `\begin{strangebox}{Your title}{2cm}` would use a kink outside, i.e. 'array' like, whereas `-2cm` would shift the kink inside by `2cm`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadows}

\newtcolorbox{strangebox}[3][]{%
  enhanced,
  nobeforeafter,
  sharp corners,
  colupper=Green4,
  colback=white,
  frame code={%
    \path[drop shadow,tcbcol@frame,fill=tcbcol@back,line width=1pt,draw] (frame.north east)  -- ($(frame.north east)!.5!([xshift=#3]frame.south east)$) -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- (frame.north west) -- cycle;
  },
 interior code={
   \path[color=tcbcol@back] (interior.north east)  -- ($(frame.north east)!.5!([xshift=#3]frame.south east)$) -- (frame.south east) -- cycle;
 },
 fonttitle=\bfseries\Large\sffamily,
 attach boxed title to top left,
 boxed title style={enhanced,colback=cyan,coltitle=white,arc=2mm, auto outer arc,boxsep=3mm},
 title={\MakeUppercase{#2}},
 width=0.8\textwidth,
 #1
}

\makeatletter
% Redefining the chapter head macro. 
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \begin{strangebox}{Activity Sheet}{-1cm}
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter~
      \fi
    \fi
%    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge\bfseries #1\par\nobreak
  }%
\end{strangebox}
}


\makeatother



\begin{document}
\chapter{Showcase: Analysing a science media article}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's shows TeX made easy and got required output, but we need "fuzzy shadow" instead of shadow in the bottom of box, I tried fuzzy shadow option it will not work. Box Width need to increase or decrease based on title.

Comment: @RajeshN: Well, as you wrote: You got required output ... `fuzzy shadow` and width change based on title was not in your initial question.

Comment: Apologize for inconvenience caused, Is there any other option to set fuzzy shadow as given in the chapter title and width.

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer: Is that possible in tcolorbox?