# tcolorbox, tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, tcolorbox

[image]

Please help us below code that right side of arrow not spanned based on height and and help us how to set auto width:
[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter

\def\@chapter[#1]#2#3{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%\thechapter
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}{#3}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}{#3}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}




\def\@makechapterhead#1#2{%
\vspace*{8pt}%
\hspace*{-3.4pt}\begin{strangebox}{#1}{-1cm}
{\parindent\z@\raggedright\normalfont%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne%
\interlinepenalty\@M%%
{\Large#2\par}\nobreak}%
\end{strangebox}
\fi
\vskip9pt%
\@afterindentfalse%
\@afterheading}%

\definecolor{ctframecolor}{cmyk}{0.07,0.03,0.12,0.10}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shadows.blur}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\definecolor{BaseColor}{HTML}{8533FF}

\newlength{\boxCornerOfset}
\setlength{\boxCornerOfset}{12pt}
\newlength{\boxShadowOfset}
\setlength{\boxShadowOfset}{2mm}

\definecolor{blackone}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.19}
\definecolor{blacktwo}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0}

% change color of shadow
\tikzset{
render blur shadow/.code=
{\pgfbs@savebb
\pgfsyssoftpath@getcurrentpath{\pgfbs@input@path}%
\pgfbs@compute@shadow@bbox
\pgfbs@process@rounding{\pgfbs@input@path}{\pgfbs@fadepath}%
\pgfbs@apply@canvas@transform
\colorlet{pstb@shadow@color}{white!\pgfbs@opacity!blackone}%
\pgfdeclarefading{shadowfading}{\pgfbs@paint@fading}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{blackone}%
\pgfsetfading{shadowfading}%
{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfbs@midx}{\pgfbs@midy}}}%
\pgfbs@usebbox{fill}%
\pgfbs@restorebb
},}


\def\framepath{\path[draw=ctframecolor,
blur shadow={shadow xshift=3pt, shadow yshift=-2pt,shadow blur steps=9,fill=white,shadow
opacity=40},
]
(frame.north east)  -- ($(frame.north east)!.5!([xshift=-50pt,]frame.south east)$) -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- (frame.north west) -- cycle;}


\newtcolorbox{strangebox}[3][]{%
  enhanced,
  nobeforeafter,
  sharp corners,
  colupper=green,colframe=ctframecolor,boxsep=7.7pt,
      frame code={%
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
            \framepath
         \end{pgfonlayer}
                },
interior code={%
            \framepath[fill=red]
                  },
 fonttitle=\Large,
 attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1.5mm,yshift=-2.21mm},
 boxed title style={colframe=cyan,colback=cyan,coltitle=white,arc=2mm, auto outer arc,boxsep=2.75mm,},
 title={\MakeUppercase{#2}},
 width=0.8\textwidth,
 #1%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\chapter{CHECKLIST}{Chapter 1}

\clearpage

\chapter{ACTIVITY SHEET}{Chapter 1 Showcase: Analysing a science media article}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you draw a sketch of how the output should look like?

Comment: This is what I get when I compile your code:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv1YN.png Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, exactly I need this one.

Comment: how do you compile your document? pdflatex, xelatex or something else? Which version of tikz do you have?

Comment: XeLaTeX, version used for tikz as (d:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)

Comment: I see. I can reproduce the problem with xelatex, but it works fine with pdflatex and lualatex. Is switching to either lualatex or pdflatex an option for you?

Comment: We using XeLaTeX for some special purpose, is there any other option to get required output?

Comment: I think this is really a problem of xelatex. Something similar is also reported here: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/492

Comment: Is there other option to set like this in TiKZ or drawing package?

Comment: I think if you use the default shadows provides in tikz you will likely have the same problem, but maybe some tikz wizard will see this question and can suggest a better course of action

Comment: When we "drop shadow" instead of "blur shadow" output came, but blur not working.

Comment: @samcarter I get the upper (=correct?) output, i,e, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv1YN.png) when compiling this with `xelatex` on my updated TeXLive 2018 distribution. Are you saying you do not get this with `xelatex`. Rajesh N : could you just update your TeXLive installation, i.e. switch to TeXLive 2019, and try again?

Comment: Thank you spending my query reply, we will check and update you.

Comment: @RajeshN: Why do you use code from my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468709/tikz-drawing-output without attribution? This is outrageous!

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446897/121799) could help.